# Ruby regex on a path

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like that :

```
//some.path/again/and/again/foo/bar/ABC_blahblah.xls
```

I want to retreive `ABC` which is always between a `/` and a `_`

I tried so far :

```
path.scan(/\/(.*)_/).last.first
```

but I get `//some.path/again/and/again/foo/bar/ABC`

I see that ruby matches the *first* `/`. How can I get what is between the *last* `\` and the `_`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're defining it wrong.  You don't want "ABC which always between a / and _.  What I think you actually want is "the first non-underscore characters in the last part of the path."  So use the [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) to get the last part of the path, and then extract the first non-underscore characters from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `\/([^\/]*)_` it will avoid having any forward slash in the captured group.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a full regex to break down a file path. Instead, rely on some pre-written code. The reason is, if you move your code to a different OS, such as Windows, it's possible you'll get file paths using different path separators. Ruby's IO and File classes are aware of the differences and will automatically adjust for you.

Compare your pure regular expression solution to something like these:

```
path = '//some.path/again/and/again/foo/bar/ABC_blahblah.xls'

File.basename(path) # => "ABC_blahblah.xls"

File.basename(path)[/^([^_]+)/, 1]      # => "ABC"
File.basename(path)[/^(.+)_/, 1]        # => "ABC"
File.basename(path).split('_', 2).first # => "ABC"
```

[File's `basename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-basename) returns the name of the file when given a path to the file.

Comment: I like your approach!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
path = "//some.path/again/and/again/foo/bar/ABC_blahblah.xls"
path.scan(/(?:[^\/])*(?=_)/).reject(&:empty?)
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient. `scan` will return an array of two elements `["ABC", ""]` requiring your `reject` or `first` or something similar.

Comment: I completely agree. Not a very performance friendly approach.